# Sliced images don't fits after resizing a page

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a problem with fitting sliced images when a page is being resized.

In a normal view (100%) everything looks fine, but when a page is resized then sometimes there's appearing a white thin strip and I really don't know why exactly it happens. Only what comes to my mind is that it can be related with rouding fractions after the page was scaled by a web browser. It happens in the Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, IE and I guess in the other browsers as well.

This's how it looks when resized to 67% in the chrome:
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcYSU.jpg)

The example contains 4 sliced images where each one has the transform scale 0.96.

```css
.container > img {
  display: block;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.container-left,
.container-right {
  width: calc((100% - 960px) / 2);
  height: 100%;
}
.container-left > img,
.container-right > img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1125px;
}
.container-left {
  left: 0;
}
.container-left > img {
  transform: scale(0.96);
  transform-origin: top right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.container-right {
  right: 0;
}
.container-right > img {
  transform: scale(0.96);
  transform-origin: top left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.container-top,
.container-center {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container-top {
  width: 960px;
  height: 120px;
}
.container-top > img {
  transform: scale(0.96);
  transform-origin: top left;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 125px;
}
.container-center {
  top: 120px;
  width: 960px;
}
.container-center > img {
  transform: scale(0.96);
  transform-origin: top left;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
#background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#site {
  width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 800px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div class="container container-left">
    <img src="http://gsroka.com/scale/left.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="container container-top">
    <img src="http://gsroka.com/scale/top.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="container container-center">
    <img src="http://gsroka.com/scale/center.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="container container-right">
    <img src="http://gsroka.com/scale/right.png" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="site">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
  galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
  containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
  leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
  versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
  a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
  recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
  the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
  Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum
  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
  not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
  like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
  type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
  Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
  dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It
  was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
  leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
  versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
  a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
  recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Comment: why not putting it as one picture ?

Comment: I'm working on a project in which I'm only getting such sliced images and I have to adjust them accordingly to a site.

Comment: could you post the in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the statement  `calc((100% - 960px)/2)` results in non integer value so browser should round it to an integer (Normal Number not floating Numbers), so it will be 1px less than what you expect. You could easily change the effect to be normal by using `calc((100% - 959px)/2)`.

#### UPDATE

Instead of using `img`, you could easily use `background-image` and `background-size: cover;` so that this would never be an issue later even while resize.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this as well, but notice that this issue also happens for the top layer (white thin strip at the bottom like in the screen that I uploaded). But even this way `calc((100% - 959px)/2)` is breaking on the Chrome while resizing a page.

Comment: @piku235 works fine in my chrome. tweak the pixels around 957px - 959px to make the adjustment. That's just what happens. You could also try the update I made to answer.

Comment: I know that I could use `background-image` and `background-size` and it'll even behave better then `transform: scale`, but I'm looking for a more universal solution, because I won't be displaying only images, but iframes as well. It's strange that this don't happen in your chrome, because in most cases the chrome was the most troublesome for me. I'm using chrome v. 48.0.2564.109.